# batch - check if variable is not empty and perform action

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch code:

```
set checkerr=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "Error" %LOG%') do @set checkerr=%%a


echo %checkerr%


if "%checkerr%" NEQ [] GOTO sendmail
```

But it is not working, I want it to send a mail only if the text string "Error" is found in the log file

Note: Errors in the log file might look like this:

```
20131117185439:       Error: Field not found - <blablabla>
20131117185445:       General Script Error
20131117185445:       Execution Failed
20131117185445:      Execution finished.
```

So there are spaces and other chars, etc

Regards

Comment: `""` is not `[]`, so of course it never equals. Use one or the other. But really you should use foxidrive's solution - a much better way of doing it.

Comment: thing is I have tried it with "" but got errors. I ended using foxdrive's solution. thanks

Comment: Also, you might have had a trailing space when you initialized checkerr. Better to use `set "checkerr="`, and then use `if "%checkerr%" NEQ "" goto sendmail`. Never-the-less, foxidrive's answer is still the way to go :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&&` operator executes the following command when errorlevel zero is generated by the preceeding command, so this should be equivalent and will branch to the `:sendmail` label when 'Error' is found in the log file.

```
findstr "Error" "%LOG%" >nul && goto :sendmail
```

The companion operator to that is `||` and this executes the following command on an errorlevel that is not zero.

To check if a variable is empty you can use this:

```
if not defined variablename goto :sendmail
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I set it up just like: findstr "Error" "%LOG%" >nul && goto :sendmail , but even though the log does not contain the string, it goes to sendmail

Comment: There is not a `:sendmail` label after the line you added is there? Because it will execute that every time, in that case.

Comment: Yes, there is . What i did is: findstr "Error" "%LOG%" >nul && goto :sendmail

goto:eof

:sendmail
...
and it works now, thanks